# Misconfigured property in core data entities

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have tried to create 3 entities in my core datas xcdatamodeld file however after my first entity was created the next two are having the same problem.

```
misconfigured property ** must have a defined type
```

just woundering what it is Im doing wrong?

Comment: That message normally means you've not set the type of an Attribute on an Entity. Perhaps try a Clean & Rebuild?

Comment: yea, thats what I thought.. but they all have attributes set.. maybe Im going to have to delete them and just start again...

Comment: turnes out even after cleaning and building the errors were still there.. then even after deleting the entities they errors were all still there too. So I just deleted the xcdatamodeld and started over.. no idea why or how that happened.

Comment: Sounds like Xcode got itself into a little tizz... did starting the xcdatamodeld from scratch fix it?

Comment: yep.. I accidentally clicked delete reference only.. and the errors stayed there :P but then i  closed xcode and went into the directory moved the offending file to the trash opened up xcode again and its all gone.. just recreated it now.. bit of a pain but not to much work lost.

Comment: Glad you got it working. You might want to answer your own question and mark it as correct...

Comment: I had a similar problem and fixed it by editing the [project_name].xcdatamodel/contents file manually (outside of xcode).

Answer (score 2):

I just went through something like this.  I had defined all inverse relationships, and there were still warnings about them not being set.

I had a peek in the contents file (inside **.xcdatamodelid->**.xcdatamodel), and there weren't any duplicates.  So, I quit XCode and restarted it.  The warnings were gone.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I fixed this by deleting the xcdatamodeld file and creating a new one with all the same objects and this worked fine for me.

It seems that xcode went abit crazy.

Comment: If this happens again see if you can create a test project with the issue and post it.  If it is an actual Xcode error it is to everyone's benefit for you to file a radar.